# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an error in 'view' in CodeIgniter ***Error look like this***

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: Invalid
>   argument supplied for foreach() Filename:
>   public/search_query_result.php Line Number: 17

[image]

Code from my **search_query_result.php**

```
<div class="container">
<h1>All Articles</h1>
<hr>
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>



<th>Sr.No</th>

    <th>Article Title</th>
    <th>Created On</th>
    </tr>
<tbody>
<?php if(count($articles)){
    $count=$this->uri->segment(3,0);    
        foreach($articles as $article){  

?>
<tr>



    <td><?=++$count;?></td>
    <td><?= $article->title?></td>
    <td><?= "Date"?></td>

</tr>
   <?php }?>
```

Code from **users.php**. This is "Controller" file:

```
function search_articles(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('query','Query','required');
    if(!$this->form_validation->run())
    $this->index();
        $query=$this->input->post('query');
        return redirect("users/search_result/$query");}
  unction search_result($query){
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->model('articlesmodel');
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config=[
                'base_url'      =>  base_url("users/search_result/$query"),
                'per_page'      => 3,
                'total_rows'    =>$this->articlesmodel->count_search_result($query),
                'full_tag_open'     =>  '<ul class="pagination"> <a >',
                'full_tag_close'    =>  '</a></ul>',
                'next_tag_open'     =>  '<li class="page-item"><a>',
                'next_tag_close'    =>  '</a></li>',
                'prev_tag_open'     =>  '<li class="page-item"><a>',
                'prev_tag_close'    =>  '</a></li>',
                'num_tag_open'      =>  '<li class="page-item"><a>',
                'num_tag_close'     =>  '</a></li>',
                'cur_tag_open'      =>  '<li class="active"><a>',
                'cur_tag_close'     =>  '</a></li>',
    ];


    $articles=$this->articlesmodel->count_search_result($query,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(4));
    $this->load->view('public/search_query_result',compact('articles'));
}
```

Code from **articlesmodel.php**. This is the model file

```
function num_rows(){
      $user_id=$this->session->userdata('user_id');

      $query=$this->db
                      ->select(['title','id'])
                      ->from('articles')
                      ->where('user_id',$user_id)

                    ->  get();
             // print_r($query->result());
      return $query->num_rows();
    }

    function search_articles( $query){
     $q=  $this->db
                  ->from('articles')
                  ->like('title',$query)
                  ->limit($limit,$offset)
                  ->get();
          return $q->result();


    }
    function count_search_result($query){
      $q= $this->db->from('articles')
                    ->like('title',$query)

                    ->get();
          return $q->num_rows();
    }
```

Comment: `count_search_result()` required three arguments you given only one, how you are getting results?

Comment: check count($articles) how much you get?

Comment: If you do a var_dump() on $articles, what do you get?

Comment: thanks dear you solve my problem 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in (users.php)

I passed wrong function name inside controller .Differencce are down...….

> before

```
$articles=$this->articlesmodel->count_search_result($query,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(4));
```

> after

```
$articles=$this->articlesmodel->search_articles($query,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(4));
```

here are difference

> `$articles=$this->articlesmodel->count_search_result` change into `$articles=$this->articlesmodel->search_articles`

Comment: update also search_articles with all args since method doesn't have any argument  in your controller till now

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code it seems like the count_search_result function will return you num_rows which is stored in $articles variable and you are trying to iterate over the variable to echo $article->title which is not available.

You have to update below controller line

```
$articles=$this->articlesmodel->count_search_result($query,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(4));
```

to

```
$articles=$this->articlesmodel->search_articles($query);
```

which will provide you required column values from articles table.